# Seating arrangement problem in a circular table

Tags: python-3.x

N people sit around a circular table. You have to find the probability that two particular people won't be sitting together.

The input will have the number N and the output should have the probability printed as a float type number rounded off to four decimal places.

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Have understood the theoretical logic and the mathematical derivation to land upto this solution. However, I am unable to conclude with a program stub.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [link](https://brainly.in/question/11866628) for the derived formula
You can find the step by step derivation over there

Here's the simple python implementation as per the thread

```py
n = 5
result = (n-3)/(n-1)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n= int(input())
import math
print(round(1-math.factorial(n-2)*math.factorial(2)/math.factorial(n-1),4))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.